# ALTER TABLE contents

Tags: mysql, sql

I was reviewing a sql dump produced by an external application and I saw something like this:

```
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `records` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

What does the line:

> ```
> /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `records` ENABLE KEYS */;
> ```

mean? Is this a comment, or something else? What is 40000?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_disable-keys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are conditional comments. The 40000 refers to a specific version of MySQL. This is to allow commands to run on versions of MySQL where they are supported and be ignored otherwise. [This blog post](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2007/05/22/how-to-write-mysql-conditional-comments/) has some more information.

Comment: thanks, so the above runs on MySQL version 4.0.0.0+ but not elsewhere? What is enable keys?

Comment: @David542 Correct. `ENABLE KEYS` causes indexes to be updated. Earlier in the file you'll see `DISABLE KEYS`. It's much more efficient to update indexes once after the full import instead of as each record is inserted.